# reference request: mercer expansion and kernel underlying Sobolev spaces?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Let us define the periodic Sobolev spaces, for $s > n/2$ by
$$
H_{s}([0, 1]^n) = \{f : [0, 1]^n \to \mathbb{R} :\mbox{for}~j\leq s,  f^{(j)} |_{\partial[0, 1]^n} \equiv 0, ~~
\int_{[0, 1]^d} (f^{(s)}(x))^2 \, dx < \infty\}
$$
It is apparently a folklore fact that $H_s([0, 1]^n)$ is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS).

In the special case that $n = s = 1$, this can be verified by showing that
this is the RKHS associated to the kernel $k(x, y) =\min\{x, y\}$, which is a Mercer kernel with respect to the uniform measure; the associated
eigenvalues and eigenfunctions take the form
$$
\lambda_j = \Big[\frac{2}{(2j-1)\pi}\Big]^{2}, \quad 
\psi_j = \sqrt{2} \sin\Big(\frac{2j - 1}{2} \pi \cdot\Big), 
\quad \mbox{for}~j \geq 1.
$$

However, is the general calculation for $n \geq 1, s > n/2$ somewhere? What is the associated kernel $k \equiv k_{s, n} \colon [0, 1]^n \times [0, 1]^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and, with respect to uniform measure, what are the eigenvalues $\lambda_j\equiv \lambda_{j, n, s}$ and eigenfunctions $\psi_j \equiv \psi_{j, n ,s}$?